# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

What are the (ring) automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

The constant polynomials must be carried to themselves by any automorphism $\varphi$. The action of $\varphi$ is then determined by $\varphi(x)$.  For $\varphi(x)$ to be surjective, $x \mapsto \pm x + b$, with $b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So, $c \mapsto c$ and $x \mapsto \pm x + b$ is a necessary condition for $\varphi$ to be an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but is it sufficient?

Comment: Yes, since the endomorphism defined as $x\longmapsto x-b$ in the inverse endomorphism of $x\longmapsto x+b$, and $x\longmapsto -x+b$ is its own inverse.